# Python print source code of local html file returns spaced out characters

Tags: python, html, regex

I have a local html file that I want to read and extract urls within the source code. However my regex would always return empty, so I tried printing out the source code and noticed that all characters are spaced out from each other. Do you know what could be the reason?

Here's my code to read the file and the regex:

```
import re
file=open("C:/Documents/name.html",'r')
content=file.read()
match = re.findall(r'<a href="(.*?)".*>(.*)</a>', content)
print(match)
```

When I tried to print content, I got:

```
< h t m l x m l n s : v = " u r n : s c h e m a s ...
```

EDIT: Thanks to abernert, this is an encoding problem and the corrected code would be:

```
import re
import codecs
file=codecs.open("C:/Users/140263/Documents/name.html",,encoding='utf-16-le')
content=file.read()
match = re.findall(r'<a href="(.*?)".*>(.*)</a>', content)
print(match)
```

Comment: Try `print(repr(content))` so we can see the actual bytes of that file. Also, I'm guessing you're on Python 2.7, but please confirm which version you're using. Also, please give us a [mcve] that's actually correct—this is just going to raise an `AttributeError` because strings don't have a `read` method.

Comment: My wild guess is that this has to do with UTF-16-LE encoding, which lots of Windows programs like to use. If you encode a bunch of mostly-ASCII text as UTF-16-LE, then read it as bytes, what you get is the ASCII bytes alternating with null bytes. If this actually is your problem, and you're on Python 2.x, the fix is to open the file as a text file with `io.open` or `codecs.open` instead of `open`, passing `encoding='utf-16-le`, and then search it with a Unicode regex like `ur'<a href="(*.?)".*>(.*)</a>'`.

Comment: I am using Python 3.4

Comment: Yes, it turns out to be the encoding problem. abarnert's suggestion worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your file is encoded in UTF-16-LE, but you're reading it as whatever your default encoding is, which isn't going to be UTF-16-LE.

Lots of Windows software uses UTF-16-LE as its default encoding for text files—which is annoying, but there's no way around it.

UTF-16-LE stores most characters as two bytes. For ASCII characters like `<` and `a`, the two bytes are the ASCII byte followed by a null byte.

So, if you read that UTF-16-LE as, say, ASCII, what you get is your characters, with null bytes in between them.

---

Usually you can diagnose this by printing the `repr` of the string, instead of the string itself, so instead of this:

```
< h t m l … >
```

… you get this:

```
'<h\0t\0m\0l\0 … >\0'
```

---

The fix is to read the file with the right encoding:

```
file = open("C:/Documents/name.html", 'r', encoding='utf-16-le')
```